# "Object expected" error while calling javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

I want to change the visibility of a textbox, according to the value selected in a dropdownlist.

I have created the function like this:

```
function ShowGiftCardSource() {
        var ddlGiftCardSource = document.getElementById('<%=ddlGiftCardSource.ClientID%>');
        var txtGiftCardSource = document.getElementById('<%=txtGiftCardSource.ClientID%>');

        if (ddlGiftCardSource.value == "Other") {
            txtGiftCardSource.style.visibility = "visible";
            txtGiftCardSource.focus();
        }
    }
```

In the CS Page:

```
ddlGiftCardSource.Attributes.Add("onChange", "OnSelectedIndexChanged();");
```

and in the control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGiftCardSource" runat="server" Width="151px" onChange="ShowGiftCardSource();">
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Could some one please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code behind to:

```
ddlGiftCardSource.Attributes.Add("onChange", "ShowGiftCardSource();");
```

And remove the `onchange` from the tag:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGiftCardOccasion" runat="server" Width="151px">
```

The `onchange` in the tag is the **server side** method to call.

Edit: in case you already have server side method you must first add AutoPostBack to the drop down then in the server side onchange event show the textbox:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGiftCardOccasion" runat="server" Width="151px" OnChange="ShowGiftCardSource" AutoPostBack="True">
```

And in your C# code behind:

```
void ShowGiftCardSource(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //code.....
  txtGiftCardSource.Visible = true;
}
```

And of course, get rid of the `ddlGiftCardSource.Attributes.Add` line.

Comment: onChange event of the ddlGiftCardSource.

Comment: @Knv You can't have both the client side event and server side event, it's meaningless. See my edit.

Comment: In the server side, there is no events of it. I told about the 'onChange', which is registered while loading the page. Actually, I have put a breakpoint on 'ShowGiftCardSource()'[JavaScript] method and executed it but nothing happened, when I selected a item from the dropdown. I'm not getting, why this is happening?, if you know any alternatives please suggest me. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry I completely lost you. I provided you with all the options, can't really explain any better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats because you are using ShowGiftCardOccasion() method in onChange handler, but you method name is ShowGiftCardSource() ? Then javascript just cannot find method with correct name.

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGiftCardSource" runat="server" Width="151px" onChange="ShowGiftCardSource();">`